# What should be in a README file in the master branch when docs are in gh-pages

Tags: github-pages

I use a `gh-pages` branch for my project documentation, but it looks like the GitHub project page requires a README file from the `master` branch.

It seems like my options are:

1. Make a copy of the `gh-pages` README in `master`, and then make sure to keep them in sync
2. Have a simple README in `master` that just points to the GitHub Pages version of the docs

Neither of these is really ideal. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could migrate your "gh-pages" branch to a subdirectory "docs" in branch "master".
And make a symlink README -> docs/README.md.

Comment: The whole value of gh-pages (and I think it is of value) is that the master branch doesn't get swamped by documentation updates.

Answer (score 0):

In a README.md file developers would expect information that help to understand the project better.

Add there only the key things about the project.

There are some tips:

- add information about the project ( what it does, what problem it solves )
- list all the key features of that project
- add the contents list of that readme file ( with links )
- add information about how to start the project & how to configure
- add some useful code snippets
- if is an open source project, add information about CONTRIBUTION
- add link to your LICENSE file into the README file

Think of that README file separate than github pages. README files should contain useful information that help the developers to understand what the project does and how to use it.

Comment: But everything in the README should also be in the github pages, and making a single doc that serves as the front door of both project and github pages is otherwise easy (and basically happens automatically when hosting from /docs)